# ¿cómo eliminar la posición de un arreglo en c++?

Tags: c++, array, c

¿Cómo elimino un elemento de una matriz y muevo los elementos restantes hacia abajo? Así que, si tengo una matriz,

```
array[]={1,2,3,4,5}
```

y quiero borrar 3 y cambiar el resto asi que tengo,
array[]={1,2,4,5}

como puedo hacer esto dentro de este condicional

```
for(int i=0;i==5;i++){
    if(array[i]==3){
    


    elimino un elemento de una matriz y muevo los elementos restantes 
  hacia abajo
    
    }
}
```

Comment: En C++ no se puede redimensionar los arreglos. Si quieres hacerlo más sencillo puedes usar `vector` o punteros.